# Get custom response header from HTTP request

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, firebug

I am fully aware this question has been posted multiple times in the past, but I can't figure it out how to fix my issue. I do a HEAD request using AJAX and get some data back in the header response, in a custom field.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Metadata");
```

Metadata is the custom field in the header. However, this always comes back as null, even though I see it in Firebug. The response is a JSON.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You should post the full code example, i.e. how you make the AJAX call etc., so people can actually see what's the problem.

Comment: The issue was I wasn't making the header accessible. It has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Custom-Header");
```

This is a fix in Java if anyone else has issues with it.